# Find $g(x)$ if $(x^2+a^2)(x^2 + b^2)(x^2 + c^2) = (f(x))^2 + (g(x))^2$ and $f(x)$ is a degree three polynomial

Tags: polynomials

If

$$(x^2+a^2)(x^2 + b^2)(x^2 + c^2) = (f(x))^2 + (g(x))^2$$

where $f(x)$ is a degree three polynomial, find $g(x)$.

The question is frankly a bit strange. The left hand side is a degree six polynomial all right, so we can expect one (or possibly both) of the polynomials $f,g$ to be a cubic. But, is there any reason to suspect that the l.h.s. would determine a *unique* fitting non-cubic polynomial? Or any fitting polynomials at all?

Anyway, I think that finding a pair of polynomials $f,g$ that satisfy this identity is a good enough beginning.

Comment: Have you tried using [this identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity)?

Comment: All. I realize that my edit may have changed the spirit of the question considerably, and also may be insufficient to raise the question above the current quality threshold. Yet, I found this problem cute enough to act, and unilaterally undelete it. If you disagree, you know what to do and/or you know the proper meta thread for discussing the fate of this question. Of course, other ideas for improving the question are more than welcome.

Comment: The solution I came up with gives the square of a cubic plus the square of a quadratic. $g(x)$ being a quadratic should make the decomposition unique. It is easily derived using the same ideas that are used when writing a number as the sum of two squares. I think this question is very interesting and should be reopened.

Comment: If $a,b,c$ are distinct, there are actually four different decompositions into the sum of two squares.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Use the following important identity twice:
$$(s^2+t^2)(u^2+v^2)=(su-tv)^2+(sv+tu)^2.$$

**Remark:** The above identity is sometimes called the [*Fibonacci Identity*,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity) although a more general identity was used by Brahmagupta many centuries before Fibonacci was born.